# Can you use a List to configure a selector in LINQ join query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `IEnumerable<DataRow>` `report1` and `report2` that I am joining

```
var query = report1
    .Join(report2, 
          row1 => row1.Field<string>("ReportID"), 
          row2 => row2.Field<string>("ReportID"), 
          (row1, row2) => new 
          {
             ReportID = row1.Field<string>("ReportID"),
             CustomerName = row1.Field<string>("CustomerName"), 
             CustomerSpending = row2.Field<string>("CustomerSpending")
          });
```

Now suppose I have two `List<string>` `fieldsReport1` and `fieldsReport2` each list contains the names of the fields from each report to make it to final join. How can modify the above query to include the lists in the results selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to create an anonymous object with dynamic fields, but there is an alternative class designed for this: the `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`. The `ExpandoObject` supports the `IDictionary<string,object>` interface to allow you to add new properties dynamically.

Using an extension method to add multiple properties at once, and chain them, you can do:

```
var query = report1
    .Join(report2,
          row1 => row1.Field<string>("ReportID"),
          row2 => row2.Field<string>("ReportID"),
          (row1, row2) => (new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string,object>).AddRange(fieldsReport1, f => f, f => row1[f]).AddRange(fieldsReport2, f => f, f => row2[f])
    );
```

BTW, how you are going to use/extract those properties is up to you. At some point, it may make more sense to just use a `Dictionary<string,object>` directly.

Here is the extension method:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> AddRange<TSrc, TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictObj, IEnumerable<TSrc> srcFields, Func<TSrc, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSrc, TValue> valueSelector) {
    foreach (var kvp in srcFields)
        if (!dictObj.ContainsKey(keySelector(kvp)))
            dictObj.Add(keySelector(kvp), valueSelector(kvp));
    return dictObj;
}
```

Note that if the two field name lists have a conflict, the first table wins. You could modify the extension method to take a key conflict resolution lambda and then fix conflicting field names how you want.

As an alternative, you can create `Dictionary`s and then convert the result to a `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> rows) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if (rows.Any()) {
        foreach (var kv in rows.First())
            dt.Columns.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value.GetType());

        foreach (var r in rows)
            dt.Rows.Add(r.Values.ToArray());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of the `ExpandoObject` and why not just use `new Dictionary<string, object>()`?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it may make more sense to use a `Dictionary`. It depends on what you intend to do with the query results. In some cases an `ExpandoObject` may work better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
var report1 = new List<DataRow>();
var report2 = new List<DataRow>();

var report1Fields = new List<string> { "ReportId", "CustomerName" };
var report2Fields = new List<string> { "CustomerSpending" };

var query = report1
    .Join(report2,
      row1 => row1.Field<string>("ReportID"),
      row2 => row2.Field<string>("ReportID"),
      (row1, row2) => new
      {
          Report1Data = report1Fields.Select(x => row1.Field<string>(x)).ToList(),
          Report2Data = report2Fields.Select(x => row2.Field<string>(x)).ToList(),
      });
```